Exact solution of SIR model
I am trying to solve the equation: $\mathbf{\frac{dR}{dt}= \gamma(N_0 - R -S_0e^{-R/\rho})}$, where $S_0e^{-R/\rho} = S(R)$ and $N_0=S+I+R$. I want to find the exact solution using separation of variables.
I find it difficult to continue from the steps below:
$\int\frac{1}{N_0 - R -S_0e^{-R/\rho}}dR=\gamma t + C$.
N.B: the equation is derived from the Kermack-Mckendrick model:
$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\beta S I$,
$\frac{dI}{dt}=\beta S I -\gamma I$, $\frac{dR}{dt}=\gamma I$

The SIR model doesn't possess a known closed form, that is why you cannot go further than the implicit integral formula you derived.

Thank you @Abezhiko. It is actually an exercise from a textbook and the authors asked for an exact solution.

WolframAlpha doesn't give a closed form for this integral or the ODE for $R$ so there is likely a mistake somewhere. Could your provide the original question and the details of your attempt?
